# Tkinter Find and Replace Function for Notepad

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I'm new at Tkinter, and python. I've been experimenting with a notepad script I've made. I'm working on a find / replace command. But I've had no luck. Here is what I've tried so far:

```
def replace():
    def replaceall():
        findtext = str(find.get(1.0, END))
        replacetext = str(replace.get(1.0, END))
        alltext = str(text.get(1.0, END))
        alltext1 = all.replace(findtext, replacetext)
        text.delete(1.0, END)
        text.insert('1.0', alltext1)
    replacebox =Tk()
    replacebox.geometry("230x150")
    replacebox.title("Replace..")
    find = Text(replacebox, height=2, width=20).pack()
    replace = Text(replacebox, height=2, width=20).pack()
    replaceallbutton = Button(replacebox, text="Replace..", command=replaceall)
    replaceallbutton.pack()
```

(this is just the function I am defining for the replace command)

The 'text' variable is on the large canvas which contains the menu's and the main text widget.

Any help is appreciated
So far I've been creating this notepad in 2.7.8, so the Tkinter import is 'Tkinter.'

What I'm shooting for is having the first box have the text to find and the second box have the text to be replaced. Upon pressing the replace button, the function replaceall() should begin.

Are there any obvious mistakes in my function, or is it just deeply flawed? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious mistake is that you are creating a second instance of `Tk`. If you need a popup window you should create an instance of `Toplevel`. You should always have exactly one instance of `Tk` running.

The second problem is related to the fact you are using a `Text` widget for the find and replace inputs. When you do a get with a second index of `END`, the string you get back will always have a newline whether the user entered one or not. If you want exactly and only what the user typed, use "end-1c" (end minus one character).

Finally, there's no reason to get all the text, replace the string, and then re-insert all the text. That will work only as long as you have no formatting or embedded widgets or images in the text widget. The text widget has a `search` command which can search for a pattern (either string or regular expression), and you can use the returned information to replace the found text with the replacement text.

Comment: Excellent feedback. Do you have a script you would recommend as a template for word-wise (Autocomplete) or paragraph-wise replacement in a tkinter text widget?